# Difference between [{}] and {} in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have been looking at the mongoose documents and I noticed this piece of code

```
 comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
```

What is the difference between using [{}] and {}. I guess this is more of a javascript thing, forgive me if i am asking a stupid question.

Comment: I guess one is an array containing an object and the other is an object.

Comment: You're defining a schema, the difference is what the data represents, an array of objects, versus an object. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[{}]` Is an array with object/s in it.
`{}` Is a object.

So in your example:
`comments`is a list of objects containing a `body` property and a `date` property, `date` is a object containing a `type` property and a `default` property.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct if it gave you the information you needed. :)